# How do I remove any app from a device using my app in android?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I am doing some experiments on my device - I want to be able to remove any application from an Android device using my application.

Given the package name of an app, how can I force the user to go to that package's uninstaller page in the Manage Applications widget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be helpful to you:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.android.myapp");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

For more and detailed information regarding the installation and uninstallation, read this question: [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
Uri AppToDelete = Uri.parse("package:" + [PACKAGE NAME GOES HERE]);
Intent RemoveApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, AppToDelete);
startActivity(RemoveApp);
```