# Android install apk with Intent

Tags: android

I need to install apk programatically. I find a method to install it with Intent:
[install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "app.apk"));
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

But, it doesn't work. The problem is the installation activity didn't appear, instead, a list of other programs is displayed for choice:

[image]

Could someone tell me what the problem is? Thanks!

Update:

1. The permission `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` is included in manifest.
2. I am running Android version 2.3 SDK 10

Comment: What is the value of "apkUri" ?

Comment: I have updated the code to show apkUri details.

Comment: The code @deepak posted is working. Are you sure the "apk" file that you want to install is located in the Download directory? Make sure both the apps don't contain same package names.

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i just include the android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES, is it enough?