# Android application self-uninstall

Tags: android, uninstallation

Is there a way to make an application uninstall itself?
For example:
I want to be able to click on an "Uninstall" button in my app and have the the app uninstall itself.

I can imagine that you can call a function of the firmware and delegate the action to it so the app gets uninstalled.

The reason I need this is that when the app is uninstalled I need to delete some files on the sdcard that were downloaded by the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can Remove your App using Intent.ACTION_DELETE

try this it work for me

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
     startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it takes the user to Uninstall screen.

Comment: Hi, I know I am super late, but do you know how to uninstall the app automatically? (i.e. no need confirmation from user)

Comment: This permission will be required in API level 28 and above. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />

Answer (score 3):

No you simply can't. At least not for the phones that are not rooted. You can take the user to an `Uninstall` screen, but they would have to click on "Uninstall" to uninstall the app. For more information visit [install/uninstall application programmatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot uninstall an app, or even detect that your app is being uninstalled. This is to preserve security and prevents malware from messing with things.

I suggest that instead of using the sd card to store files, you use internal storage. These files are deleted automatically when the app is uninstalled.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal