# Android - Download and Install apk file in Webview 

Tags: android, webview, download, installation, apk

I am trying to make a simple webview for my mobile website.
There are app link `.apk` on that website and I need to detect when user click on those link. After clicking file will be downloaded to SD card, then form user to install if want to..

I have read many solutions but did not get working solution yet.

Now all good at step to detect the `.apk` file, but it seem open default browser for those download link in second then go off, and I don't know how to auto-form install after downloaded.

[My Code](http://pastebin.com/igRzbLyc) that I used.

Comment: It's much better to link user to Google Play page of your app. Just an advice.

Comment: Sorry ! The apps is beta and only user for specific user groups, can not upload to market.

Comment: Tried running your source the website is down

Comment: You just need to read up on BroadcastReceivers. On a side-note, what do you mean by "auto-form install"? Do you mean automatically install without user-intervention? Or do you mean automatically bringing up a dialog with the usual app permissions requesting if the user is willing to install the application?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the embedded webview wont have all the features that the normal browser has. Therefore, once you catch the click on the apk then you have to do one of the following

1. Download the file via the Android DownloadManager (example here http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)
2. Download the file yourself via `HttpUrlConnection`

Once the download has completed, you can try and kick off the install via an Intent (most likely Intent.ACTION_VIEW) or install directly via `PackageManager`.
See here [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)