# Launch .apk file on Android device

Tags: android, shell

Might seem a pleonasm the 'Title' but I wrote it to emphasize the issue.
I have an application running on an Android device, using the 2.2 Froyo library. The application has to (1) install - if not already installed - then (2) launch an .apk file already present in the data/data/myapp/files/ folder.
Knowing Java I would have used a shell execution of the above operations. But Android is also a separate namespace, therefore I would like to know how to do the sequence install + launch of the .apk file.
To note that, while I'm using Eclipse/Ubuntu now, the implementation should take into account ONLY the Android OS APIs, not my dev environment available tools.
Thanks

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents

Comment: @zapl: May thanks, that's what I was looking for. Since you put it as a comment I can't mark it as THE answer, but that's what it is!

Comment: Just a link is not an answer, more a reason to close this question because it's a duplicate of the linked one :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not launch an apk file. An apk file can be thought of as a container holding some number of activities, services, receivers, among other constructs. It's likely you mean you want to launch an activity (which is performed using the `startActivity()` method from the `Context` class, or one of its many subclasses) but by no means is that a certainty.

It would seem from your question that you need to learn quite a bit about Android before continuing on the path suggested by your question, because the question you've posted is really too vague to be answered in a reasonable manner for stackoverflow.

Comment: When people ask questions is because they are missing information. Anything can be learned if we'd have time. So 'learn quite a bit about Android ...' makes sense more or less, I take it positive anyway. It's true that my fingers typed too fast (I know what apk is), but, as I mentioned, I want to install first the application contained in the .apk file. That's the first question. Then, I want to launch THIS installed application, which - thanks! - can be performed through startActivity(). Following your help it remains just the first question ;-) ...

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help in some manner. Please understand still though -- there is no such thing as launching an Android application either. Terminology may seem arbitrary however it's all we have to communicate with on a common ground, and when using the wrong terminology, communications (such as asking questions and receiving appropriate answers) suffers. I'm not trying to be nit-picky, I'm trying to help you.