# Android Application Update Automatically

Tags: android

I have created simple Android Application to send a email, Application is Works Fine. I Created a one service to download and install Android Application form server[i don't want to put that Application in Marketplace]

I have update that Android Application in Future and built as a apk then upload it in server

**Problem is In device i need to update that Application if i did some changes in Application**

Give some useful ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set up an API on your server which will tell your app if new updates are available. This API has to be checked periodically. If there is a new update, then this can be downloaded and installed and the original one uninstalled.

Another way is to use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). You can set it up such that your app will get notification from your server when an update is available and then you can do as earlier.

Have a look at this thread to see how to uninstall and install packages:

[install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

If you don't wanna uninstall/install manually, then you can use this excellent package from CommonsWare:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater

If you wanna use a framework then there are many options:

http://hockeykit.net/index.html

http://launchpadapp.com/

http://www.appaloosa-store.com/

http://www.apphance.com/

Comment: is it possible to update that application instead of installing and uninstalling programmatically?

Comment: We use http://www.appaloosa-store.com/ and it's perfect for this use case. It's a private app store solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may want to try something like hockeykit http://hockeykit.net/index.html