# How install/ uninstall apk android with phoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to install and to uninstall an android apk using phoneGap?

Comment: as in, you have the apk and you want to install it on the device? or you have a phonegap application and you want to create an apk?

Comment: I have the apk and i want to install it on the device

Comment: Hi lady android, do you want to automatically install phonegap apk once its downloaded? because i'm facing similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), which is now known as [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), depends on the standard Android SDK for Android development. As such, installation works the same way as for "native" Android applications (see the "Deploy to" sections in the [Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) guide). Besides using Eclipse, you can also use some [Cordova helper scripts](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage_android) to deploy applications, or simply use the Android SDK's [adb (un)install](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#move) directly.

If you question is whether PhoneGap offers an API to programmatically (un)install an application, the answer is no. This can only be done with "native" code and [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something why not `Android SDK/platform-tools/adb install your.apk`

Comment: That's what I was referring to with "use the Android SDK's adb (un)install directly"...

Comment: Or the Cordova way, `cordova run android --device` if you want to deploy to your device. Just make sure your device is tethered to your dev mac/pc and `USB debbugging` is enabled on the device. `Settings > About Phone > Build number > Tap it 7 times to become developer` or `Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging`

Comment: You could also use `phonegap run android`

Answer (score 4):

You can e-mail the apk to you and open the attachment on the device. Android will see that the file is an android application and ask you if you want to install it on your device.

Note that if you do this you have to allow third party applications to be installed on your device. In the developer options you have to enable applications from unkown sources.

To uninstall you have to follow the same steps as any other application on your device. Go to settings -> applications => find app => uninstall

If you have the phonegap app imported in eclipse you can run directly to the device as native android apps.

also check out:
http://droidlessons.com/how-to-install-non-market-third-party-apps-on-android/

Comment: I'm so sorry but this is not what i want.I need to install an apk file with phonegap functionnality if it exist.

Comment: Settings -> Security -> Unknown Sources -> "Allow"