# How to Generate a "self-referring" URI for Self-Uninstallation Prompt?

Tags: android, uri, uninstallation

In here:
[install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

The poster refers to  an apkUri for uninstalling an APK.  How would I have the android app generate a Uri to itself?  And/or what would a URI to an app's own APK look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.android.myapp");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Make sure to replace `com.android.myapp` with your package name

Comment: I have done this, but nothing seems to happen.  I do not see a prompt to remove the application, or anything along those lines.  No error is being generated in logcat either.

Comment: @RaymondB I just tried it out and it works perfectly for me. Are you calling the code from an Activity?

Comment: No, it is a service; I've seen a few mentions where I might need to add a flag to the intent to start an activity, would that be it?

Edit: I just needed to add:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);