# how to add app sharing option for share the entire application by apk in local assets and by play store link

Tags: flutter, apk, share

want to add option for sharing a flutter application by link and by apk from local folder

two buttons in flutter application to share the entire application apk by bluetooth and by play store link

Comment: Is your app distributed via Google Play? Because if it is installed through Play Store you don't have one APK file but multiple APK files adapted o the current device. So if the sharing target device is different (screen, CPU, language) local sharing doesn't make sense as the relevant APK parts are missing.

Comment: Not distributed via Google play

Comment: Anyone please help me to complete the application.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16973248/150978