# How to uninstall android system app programmatically?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I can get a list of installed apps (both user and system apps). I am also able to uninstall user apps, however, not able to uninstall system apps.

Is there any way to uninstall system app?
If the phone is already rooted, will the following code work?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+appPackageName.getText().toString()));
                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Below link may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can execute root commands with:

```
runCommand("su");
runCommand("rm /data/system/application.package.apk");
runCommand("rm /data/data/application.package");

//when this doesn´t work try
runCommand("rm -r /data/system/application.package.apk");
runCommand("rm -r /data/data/application.package");

public static void runCommand(String command){
try {
        Process chmod = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(chmod.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();
        chmod.waitFor();
        outputString =  output.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

There is also a nice library: https://github.com/Free-Software-for-Android/RootCommands

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `root` access in order to remove `system` or `vendor` apps.

```
$ su
# rm /data/system/application.package.apk
# rm /data/data/application.package
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Rooted Device...it works

```
        Process reboot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(reboot.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("pm uninstall co.example.demo\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        reboot.waitFor();
```