# How to uninstall system apps programatically after Android O?

Tags: android, root

I am making an app that can uninstall system apps. After going through all the answers from StackOverFlow, I can say that 99% of them are via ADB and the one which I found useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399068/9953518 ,this is now changed from Android O.

According to this article https://medium.com/@quaful/the-changes-of-apk-install-location-since-android-oreo-e646d1b53c4d it is now not possible to navigate to a specific folder of the app and we are bound to use .sourceDir. The problem that I have is after requesting for the root and getting the sourceDir, the .apk file doesn't uninstall and if it does, the complete files are not uninstalled or removed in this case. I am using the code below :

```
//appsSelected is the array with all the package names of the system apps selected to be uninstalled
        case "uninstall":
            for (int i = 0; i < appsSelected.size(); ++i) {
                final int finalI = i;
                Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        RootManager.getInstance().obtainPermission();
                        System.out.println("Public directory is  "+ yup(appsSelected.get(finalI)));
                        runCommand("rm -rf "+ yup(appsSelected.get(finalI)) );

                    }
                });
                worker.start();
            }

            break;
```

This is the fucntion that returns the filePath:

```
String yup(String pack){
    PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo p = null;
    try {
        p = m.getPackageInfo(pack, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p.applicationInfo.sourceDir;
}
```

Finally the function that runs the commands:

```
  public static void runCommand(String command) {
    try {
        Process chmod = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(chmod.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();
        chmod.waitFor();
        String outputString = output.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have the root permission ("su" command) and all the permissions required.

Answer (score 0):

At first, run:

```
pm uninstall <package_name>
```

Then,

```
rm -r <applicationinfo.sourceDir>
```

Then,

```
rm -r <applicationinfo.publicSourceDir>
```

Then reboot the device, and the app should be uninstalled.

N.B: All these command should run as root!