# Intent to uninstall user apps android

Tags: android

My app displays all user apps in a `ListView`, I want to take the user to the screen where they can uninstall that app onclick. However, the code I am using opens the info screen for about 1/4 second and then takes the user back to the app. Where am I wrong??

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String packageName = results.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I would like to take the user directly to the message where it asks "are you sure you want to uninstall <appname>.apk?"

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below code :

```
String app_pkg_name = "com.example.app";
int UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);  
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));  
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

For more detail refer [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Comment: Did you really READ the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will work for Android 4.0 and above. For all versions use `Intent.ACTION_DELETE`

Comment: i want it to be compatible with all api levels. thanks

Comment: Use Intent.ACTION_DELETE then.

Comment: i tried it and it says "The app wasn't found in the list of installed apps." for every app i click

Comment: That would make me think your package name convention is wrong.

Comment: hmmm, then what could be the resolution? i can show you the full code if you invite me to the chat

Comment: Is this how you are getting the package names? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/1212314

Comment: im not sure, it uses package manager to get all package, and i think it assigns it in some array thing and then is rendered in a listview using an adapter.

Comment: Replace your getInstalledApps logic with the code in the answer I linked to.

Comment: uhm, i'm not sure how to do that. a snippet would be a really nice idea!

Comment: can you tell me where exactly should i place this?

Comment: If you don't know how to replace the code in a method there is no hope for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exception ?

```
try {
    //Open the specific App Info page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
    //e.printStackTrace();

    //Open the generic Apps page:
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```