# Is it possible to ask confirmation before uninstall android app?

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Android. I'm making an app that need to ask a password before uninstall without rooting the phone, but after a lot of research i understood that this is not possible (correct me if i'm wrong). Now i'm trying to understand if it is possible to show a tab or anything else which asks confirmation before uninstalling my app. I'm almost sure it is not possible, but I'm asking here because maybe some more experienced user can help me.
I'm using API level 21+.
If my question is not clear or more information is required tell me and I will update this question.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: No its not possible as uninstall  operation will be done by system os and system will anyway ask

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. The uninstall operation is being performed by the Android system and there's no way to influence the way it performs this task. If this would be possible, everyone would do it and it would cause nothing, but annoyed users.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible however I did look at this question. I believe this is a possible solution to the problem?

If you can just make a popup window and let the user accept/decline the install/uninstall operation?

[install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not what i asked for. Thanks anyway