# Remove app from admin & uninstall

Tags: android

I have two apps on a device , both admin with packages : 
com.mycomp.firstapp & com.mycomp.secondapp

I want one of them to remove the admin and uninstall the other ,

Is there any silent way to do it ? ( without any user interface only in the background )

Even a way of doing only one is good , I have an old non tech crowd and it will be a trouble for them to remove admin or even uninstall.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to uninstall other app, even with admin rights.

Comment: [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7705438/2794507)