# How to uninstall an Android app programmatically without user interaction?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a parental control android app which has the ability to uninstall android apps installed on the mobile phone. I referred answers for the question [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

I used the following code to uninstall a specific application.

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);      intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.tharindurasanga.locationtracker"));
startActivity(intent);`

**This code really works fine but not giving what I'm expecting since this is resulting a prompt saying user to confirm the app uninstallation. I need to uninstall the app silently without user confirmation.**

Can someone suggest me another method of doing this or help me to remove this prompt. Note: my device has root permissions too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Comment: @Torben I need to uninstall the app silently without user confirmation. Answers to this question don't provide solutions specifically for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this method on **rooted device**

```
    try{
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("pm uninstall package_name\n");
    outputStream.flush();

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    su.waitFor();
}catch(IOException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done for the 3rd party apps as this privilege is only available to the system apps. This is also not available by `JavaReflection`.

Refer: [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Comment: Is there any method available for rooted devices?

Comment: Nope. The user interface will be there.