# Delphi Android uninstall other apps from my application?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is it possible to run code to uninstall my specific applications? I have found it how to do it on Android Studio but how would I go on doing it in RAD studio?

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uninstall com.whatsapp");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

This is used in a Company device, so I need to be able to uninstall this.

Comment: it is not possible at all (without root access)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents

Comment: Think of it this way: What would you think, if some competitor chose to remove your app, just because he can?

Comment: @Sherlock70 As I MENTIONED above "This is used in a Company device, so I need to be able to uninstall this."

Comment: @TechnerBlade: But if you can do it on your company device, someone could do it on a non-company device, which would be both a massive security issue and an abusive privilege risk. As Sherlock70 MENTIONED, a developer/company could remove their competitor's apps without consent from the user.