# Batch APK install programmatically

Tags: android, apk

I have a backup restore application and I'm trying to figure out how to install Multiple APKs one after another.

I install apps using intent.
I just can't figure out how to have them batch install one after another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Comment: I can get it to install one apk. When I try running multiple apks that's where I get in problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No not yet unfortunately.

Comment: I'm working on it. If I find a way, will post here.

Comment: Cool. Thank you.