# How to uninstall android app using adb commands in the app code itself?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, kiosk

I want a uninstall an app without poping the "Do you want to uninstall this app?" dialog.

I have tried using

```
try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm uninstall --user 0 packageName")
    }catch (e : Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()        
    }
```

Getting the below error

```
Exception occurred while dumping:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:94)
        at com.android.server.AppOpsService.checkPackage(AppOpsService.java:974)
        at android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(AppOpsManager.java:1656)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:874)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:792)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:118)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:94)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:18695)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:468)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2408)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3083)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Note: INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission is added in the AndroidManifest file and also the app is signed as a system app

Answer (score 1):

> This is not currently available to third party applications. Note that
> even using reflection or other tricks to access installPackage() will
> not help, because only system applications can use it. (This is
> because it is the low-level install mechanism, after the permissions
> have been approved by the user, so it is not safe for regular
> applications to have access to.)
>
> Also the installPackage() function arguments have often changed
> between platform releases, so anything you do trying access it will
> fail on various other versions of the platform.

However for uninstalling an app using ADB command line you can use

`adb uninstall <package_name>`

You can refer the below link to another similar thread.

[install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

Comment: `adb uninstall <package_name>`

This isn't working.

Comment: I hope you are doing it via command line. Additionally make it sure you are passing the correct package name.