# Callback for programatically install .apk

Tags: android, android-intent, callback, apk

I update my app using a local downloaded `.apk`, via `DownloadManager`, using this code:

```
val installIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            installIntent.setDataAndType(localUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
            installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            this.startActivity(installIntent)
```

Although most of the time it works, sometimes, only some of the users get the `"There was a problem parsing the package error"` popup.

I'm interested if there is any callback that we can get in our app, whenever this happens, or user press 'OK' in the popoup . I found [here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents), a callback that checks if the package exists (meaning that it was installed) but I'm more interested for updates, in this case I already know that the app was previously installed.

Is there a callback (maybe `startActivityForResults`) for this specific intent, so we know that it was successfully installed or it failed?

Comment: Perhaps, rather than use `ACTION_VIEW`, you could use [`PackageInstaller`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller). [Here is a sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller) demonstrating its use.

Comment: @CommonsWare It worked using package installer. At least for unsuccessfully installation, for success usually goes to launcher main screen. If you turn your comment into a response, I'm gonna accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_VIEW` is not designed to return a result. On Android 5.0 and higher, `PackageInstaller` gives you a direct API for installing apps, where you can provide a callback (in the form of an `IntentSender`) to find out about how the installation proceeds.

[This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller) shows the basics of using `PackageInstaller`, and you should be able to find open source apps that use it in a more sophisticated fashion. For example, the F-Droid client probably uses `PackageInstaller`.