# Install apk without downloading

Tags: android, streaming, client-server

Can I install `apk` file without downloading? The `apk` file is on the server. I tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
public static void InstallProgram(Uri uri, Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);           
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);     
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Where `uri` is `http://192.168.43.1:6789/mobile_base/test.apk`.
It returns an error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://192.168.43.1:6789/mobile_base/test.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952516/install-apk-from-url

Comment: I also want to install android application without downloading from my own server. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadPath + fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you can use this code .may be solve the problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://192.168.43.1:6789/mobile_base/test.apk"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

For this your android application must have uploaded into the android market. when you upload it on the android market then use the following code to open the market with your android application.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=<packagename>"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want it to download and install from your own server then use the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/sample/test.apk"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. You forgot about `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` But I don't want to download file. So if there is no any solution. I'm going to download it first before install.